# Umbraco - Dynamic Layout for the Site

Tags: umbraco

We are using Umbraco 4.5 in our Application. We need to deploy same application on multiple different servers. The core features of the system will remains the same but, we need different Look & Feel for all the site.

Eg. Layout (2 Column, 3 Column), Skin & Theme will be different for each site

so, we need same source code on multiple sites but UI will be different so, in Umbraco - we need to add all different UI (Skin, Theme, Images, CSS etc) and based on configuration specific

How can we get this done?

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at the skinning technology in umbraco

see also: 
http://umbraco.com/help-and-support/video-tutorials/creating-a-skin-for-umbraco